# Command to query list of all objects/resources using a specific API version in kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have an application running on EKS 1.21 and we are in the process of upgrading to EKS 1.22 since 1.21 will reach end of support in Feb 2023. I am trying to figure out a kubectl command or something similar that can query the entire cluster for any v1beta1 API versions that are deprecated and replaced by GA v1 as per :-

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/update-cluster.html#update-1.22

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#v1-22

Is there a comprehensive consolidated kubectl command that can be used to see if there is any YAML manifest in the cluster that still uses v1beta1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below command would return the namespace, name, apiVersion, and all the resources in your cluster. You can pipe this with grep to filter wherever you want.

```
kubectl api-resources --no-headers  |while read type ignore; do kubectl get $type  -A -o go-template='{{range $index,$pod := .items}}{{(or .metadata.name  "-")}} {{(or .metadata.namespace "-")}} {{ (or .kind "-")}} {{ (or .apiVersion  "-") }} {{"\n"}}{{end}}'  2>/dev/null; done
```